# Network Load Balancing - Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, load-balancing

I have 2 virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 instances that I am load balancing with Widnows Network Load Balancing. Since they are on vmware, each machine has 1 nic and uses multicast mode.

With multicast mode, the ip address of the cluster and the server are both on the same nic.

Whenever the server goes out to the network, will it use it's own private ip or will it sometimes use the cluster IP address? What would be a good way to check?

Answer (score 2):

Communication from the server should be from the dedicated ip address, not the NLB ip address. You should be able to confirm this by running "netstat -a -n -o" from a command prompt on the server(s).